# Link to bootstrap not working in Angular 2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

In index.html as shown below, I am trying to link to bootstrap.css located in node_modules folder but getting an error.

Folder structure of application:

ecommerce-app/node_modules

ecommerce-app/src/app/index.html

In index.html, all of the following references to bootstrap.css produced errors:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

This is the error:
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 
NOT FOUND

Comment: check if they are not in an `assets` folder. Such as: `assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: bootstrap.css is definitely in the node_module folder as shown in the above links. I have one file in assets, ecommerce.css, and the link to it works fine: <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ecommerce.css">

Comment: Are you using Angular-CLI?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem in Angular-CLI.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular-CLI, add this to your `angular-cli.json`:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
```

Comment: localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Tweak the pathing. Try removing the `../`, or changing it for `./`.

Comment: I had tried ../ previously. ./ is not working either.

Comment: Where is your `angular-cli.json`? Is it in a subfolder?

Comment: angular-cli.json is in the src folder: ecommerce/src. I have put bootstrap.css in assets and it seems to be working for now. Guess I will use it as a temporary solution.

Comment: try `"src/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"` in yout `angular-cli.json`. That should do it. Let me know please! hope it helped! :D

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier. Just saw your message. node_modules and src are in the same folder so that would not work. I tried it anyway and got an error: ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./src/src/~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css. I then included the top level directory where node_module is located in the path but this didnt work either: "/test01/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: This worked: "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css". Thank you.

Comment: @koque I'm glad I was of help. You have my +1! Keep it up mate! ;)

Comment: @koque This will work and add bootstrap.css to the styles bundle so you can remove the link from your index.html it isn't needed.